# Image source in Class Library

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I am trying to create a user control for my WinRT app, and for that I created a class library in my solution.
The class library has a folder named "Images" with an icon.png in it. In the Generic.xaml file, in the controls template I have this:

```
<Style TargetType="local:MyControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyControl">
                <Button Background="Transparent">
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <Image Source="/Images/icon.png" Width="64" Height="64"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

When I use this control in the app no image is displaying. I dont know what the problem is. I have tried using ms-appx, and ../ but nothing works. The images Build Options are set to Content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use the following format instead:

```
Source="ms-appx:///MyLibrary/Images/icon.png" />
```

replacing MyLibrary with the name of your dll.

Comment: this does not work for me, now its searching in the directory MyLibrary/MyLibrary/Images/icon.png

Comment: This works great when I run my app, but Visual Studio or Resharper says that the file is not found so I was thinking that it wouldnt work, anyway, thanks